# Dismissing Stripe Keyboard when Screen Tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, stripe-payments

I've been struggling with this as I've found no help on SO and haven't been fully able to comprehend Stripe's framework descriptions.

I'm trying to dismiss the Stripe keyboard when a user taps the screen. My UIGesture is working properly, but I'm not sure how to get rid of the stripe keyboard after the tap is detected.

I've tried the below:

```
-(void)tapDetected:(id)sender{
    [self.visibleScrollView resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Any thoughts or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: keyboard is always connected with textfield not scrollview so instead of using [self.visibleScrollView resignFirstResponder]; use that textfield for resignFirstResponder method call.